# python networkx more than two edges between two nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, label

I have a file with this kind of data

```
497014;5674;200
5674;5831;400
410912;5674;68.5
7481;5674;150
5831;5674;200
5831;5674;300
```

The first two elements are nodes while the third is a label (parameter specific of a particular relation between the nodes). You can plot the data with this code (python 3.4, networkx 1.9) (thanks to @mdml)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data= open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test-py.csv", "r")
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
edge_labels = dict()
for line in data:
    node1, node2, weight1 = (line.strip()).split(";")
    length = float(weight1)
    G.add_edge(node1, node2, label=str(weight1), length=length)
    edge_labels[(node1, node2)] = weight1 # store the string version as a label

# Draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) # set the positions of the nodes/edges/labels
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos) # draw everything but the edge labels
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.3) 
# label_pos needed to not overwrite when you have two labels
plt.show()
```

But how can I draw three (or more) labeled edges between two nodes (as, for example, between nodes 5831 and 5674)?

Thanks.

#

I modified the previous code to add a unique key to the records to use with Multi kind of graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test-py.csv", "r")
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()  #for the example below Undirected I used the MultiGraph() version
edge_labels = dict()
k=0 # added
for line in data:
    node1, node2, weight1 = (line.strip()).split(";")
    length = float(weight1) 
    G.add_edge(node1, node2, key=str(k), label=str(weight1), length=length) 
    # modified with key
    edge_labels[(node1, node2)] = weight1 
    k+=1 # added
# Draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos) 
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.3)
plt.show()
```

It is possible to query data to extract information.
For example, between nodes 5674 and 5831:

Directed (with MultiDiGraph())

```
>>> G.get_edge_data('5674', '5831')
{'1': {'length': 400.0, 'label': '400'}}

>>> G.get_edge_data('5831','5674')
{'5': {'length': 300.0, 'label': '300'}, '4': {'length': 200.0, 'label': '200'}}
```

Undirected (with MultiGraph())

```
>>> G.get_edge_data('5674', '5831')
{'5': {'length': 300.0, 'label': '300'}, '4': {'length': 200.0, 'label': '200'}, '1': {'length': 400.0, 'label': '400'}}
```

But graphs are the same as before: only one connection between nodes.
I want to use the power of visualization to get more (high level) information in less time. For this reason I'm interested with "how can I draw/plot this data?".
I'll continue the tests.

Thanks again.

Comment: use [multigraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes.multidigraph.html?highlight=multi%20graph#networkx.MultiDiGraph)?

Comment: Hi @sophiadw, ok but at the moment I've haven't found how.Do you have an example of code I can use to plot at least 3 edges between 2 nodes (and, if possible, with labels too)? I'm going to edit my post to add info

Comment: I couldn't find a way to display the Multigraph with matplotlib. You might want to use something else for the multigraph visualisation